# server address and ip in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, python, ip

I have not used ubuntu much, only when I have to deploy a web. Right now I am trying to deploy a python django web, but I have an issue with ip address.

So, I tried `python manage.py runserver` at first, and it gave timed-out errors. Server address, which I was told by my supervisor and which I can only access via putty, is xxx.yy.zzz.aaa. When I tried to deploy my python django web specifically to this address by using `python manage.py runserver xxx.yy.zzz.aaa:8000`, I get an error saying

> that ip address can't be assigned to.

I used few other ports like 8001, but still it did not work.

So, I used the following command to see what ip address is.

`ifconfig`

And I got three addresses: one is localhost (127.0.0.1), the other is related to docker, which I did not create. The third is under hostname enp---, but it is **not** xxx.yy.zzz.aaa. It is completely different one.

So, then, I googled some more and I used the following command.

`curl https://ipinfo.io/ip`

Then, I get the "correct" address xxx.yy.zzz.aaa.

I do not know much about network and ip in ubuntu, but can ubuntu have different ip's besides docker ip address? If so, then how can I set the ip address so that I can use xxx.yy.zzz.aaa to deploy python django web?

Comment: As I understand it, a Django server process listens for incoming connections at a given port, which is 8080 by default. It may be that another process has already claimed that port. Either deploy your Django web at another port, or find out which process is running at that port (`sudo netstat -tulpn`) and kill it.

Comment: @Jos Jenkins is running at port 8080, so I tried to run Django at port 8000 by using ```python manage.py runserver xxx.yy.zzz.aaa:8000```, but still it does not work. I did the same for all other addresses including docker just in case, but still no luck.

Comment: This is useful information. Please add it to your question (comments are sometimes cleaned up).

Comment: @Jos, just edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Your server probably sits behind a NAT, and public (external) IP address xxx.yy.zzz.aaa is being translated to the internal (private) one you see on enp--- interface. The translation is done probably somewhere **outside** your server. You need to get more information about that NAT, because the only thing you know right now is that the NAT forwards requests to port 22 (ssh) on xxx.yy.zzz.aaa to your Ubuntu server. It is not known whether it forwards any other ports that you can use for your web app.

Comment: @raj thanks. Then, I have to find more about NAT and that whole translating ip address situation. In the meantime, do you know, by any chance, if, and how, I could use external ip address to deploy django? If I understood correctly, I should be able to access django when I deploy it to 0:8000, but I can't right now.

Comment: Without knowledge about the NAT configuration, it's hard to say on which address and port you can deploy the app and if this is possible at all without changing the NAT configuration.

Comment: @raj okay, got it. Thanks. At least now I know how I should go about this.